# How do I replace single whitespaces without affecting multi-whitespace such as indentation in Vim?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, replace, whitespace, search-replace

I have textfiles with paths that have lost underscores between words inline in an OCR process. I want to keep the indentation and put back the underscores in the paths.

I have a path like this:

```
    /dir/file name and stuff
```

I want it to look like this:

```
    /dir/file_name_and_stuff
```

If I try:

```
:s/\s/_/g
```

I get:

```
____/dir/file_name_and_stuff
```

Answer (score 9):

The substitution is easier to read with word-boundaries in my opinion, and very magic mode makes typing easier:

```
:%substitute/\v>\s+</_/g
```

Comment: Very cool. Shorter and easier to read. Thank you for that :)

Comment: @RasmusGroth that's what upvotes are for :) see [Voting up](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up), though it looks like you don't quite have that privilege yet :(

Answer (score 2):

I found [this answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/64glrh/comment/dg252id) posted by [u/rewardit](https://www.reddit.com/user/redwardit/) on Reddit which does the trick, but I didn't find anything on SO or networked sites so thought I would post it here as I prefer this format to Reddit

This will remove all single whitespaces

```
:s/\(\S\)\s\+/\1 /g
```

This will remove single whitespaces between words, but not multiple whitespaces at the end of the line:

```
:%s/\(\S\)\s\+\(\S\)/\1 \2/g
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Self-answering is allowed and encouraged, no need to call that out in the post :)

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble - and thanks for improving on the answer 